# javascript learning, while if

Tags: javascript

this may seem stupid to some, but please try and help me see sense here, I'm currently learning javascript and one of my challenges is as follows

> In countdown.js below, modify the while-loop with a conditional that will only allow a number to be printed if it is even. Your results should be the even numbers from 10 to 2 descending. Think carefully about how your code might decide if a number is even…

If I use the code below I get the answer 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, but if I change it to num + 1 in the log out it works. I thought the decrement would occur after the log out put?

```
var num = 10;

while (num > 0) {
    if (num % 2) {
        console.log(num); // can't be right??????
    }
    num--;
}
```

Comment: `if (num % 2 == 0) {`

Answer (score 7):

The test in your `if` statement, `num % 2`, is true when the value in "num" is **not** divisible by 2. The `%` operator gives the remainder after a division, so when the remainder is non-zero, it's `true`.

If you want even numbers, use `!(num % 2)`, which will be `true` when the remainder is zero, or perhaps more explicitly `num % 2 === 0`.

Comment: Does somebody disagree with me about what an even number is?

Comment: Yes, @Pointy, I disagree.

Answer (score 3):

0 == false, and 1 == true.  % division returns the remainder, so 3 % 2 = 1, which evaluates to true.  Negate your comparision: `if( ! num % 2 )`;

Alternately, use `if( num % 2 === 0 )`, which may be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if (num % 2 === 0)` instead of `if (num % 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers adequately explain the problem, but I want to go into the technical details.

Javascript converts between types, just, all the time<sup>1</sup>. The module operator returns an integer, but the if construct expects a boolean, so Javascript is going to convert between them.

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp) page shows how Javascript converts different types to booleans. As you can see, an integer value of 0 (which, in your case, will be when the number is even), will be converted to a boolean false.

The proper way to correct this, as others have noted, is to use the explicit test `(num%2) === 0` (The `===` operator is strict equality, which is generally preferred by Javascript programmers for reasons that belong in another question)

---

<sup>1</sup> **EDIT:** I used to use the word "constantly" here, but I replaced it because I didn't want to confuse my meaning with the computer science meaning of a constant-time operation

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters your num % 2 isn't doing anything. You can mod any number with any other number and it'll return something. What you're looking for is whether the number contained within num is divisible by 2. So, you'd need to do something like the following:

```
var num = 10;
while(num > 1) {
 if (num % 2 === 0){
   console.log(num);
 }
num--;
}
```

I changed your `while` statement to stop at 1 so that you only count down to the number 2, per your instructions.